# Python Remove if Not Found

Tags: python, list, sortedset

The code below works but I am interested if there a shorter/more elegant/more "Pythonic" way to program the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

def removeSubsumed(L, R):
    """Returns those lists in L that are not supersets of any list in R"""
    result = []
    for l in L:
        fg = True
        for r in R:
            if l >= r:
                fg = False
                break
        if fg:
            result.append(l)
    return result

print removeSubsumed([ SortedSet([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]),
                       SortedSet([ 'd', 'e', 'f' ]),
                       SortedSet([ 'g', 'h', 'i' ]) ],
                     [ SortedSet([ 'a', 'b' ]),
                       SortedSet([ 'g' ]) ])
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is supposed to do. You appear to be only interested in members of `L` that are larger than any value in `R`, but this is totally different than your docstring. Additionally, your `fg` appears to me to be completely superfluous, but I might be misreading your intent.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist if `l` and `r` are of type (or a subtype of) set , then `l >= r` checks whether l is a superset of r , or r is a subset of l.

Comment: Operator >= is overloaded in SortedSet to check if left list is a super set of right list.

Comment: I would like to point out that the docstring references **lists in L** and **lists in R**. If the function is only supposed to work on lists of sets, note that. Otherwise, my point stands: the intent of this function directly conflicts with its docstring. Also, if it's only supposed to work on lists of sets, consider renaming the function and/or duck typing to prevent invalid values.

Comment: why are you using SortedSets?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Thanks, I will update docstring that function is supposed to work on sorted sets only. Is there a good way to assert this?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: because this is part of a larger module :)

Comment: @major4x If you're only interested in `SortedSet` or things that behave like `set` (and therefore likely inherit from it), I would just do a simple `isinstance` test and raise something like `ValueError` if it's not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and list comprehension . Example -

```
def removeSubsumed(L, R):
    return [s for s in L if not any(s >= r for r in R)]
```

[`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) - Return True if any element is True, otherwise returns False (even if the iterable it receives as argument is empty).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try a functional way, but I have to say, that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484019/python-remove-if-not-found/32484167#32484167) approach works much more faster:

```
def removeSubsumed(L, R):
    return filter(lambda l: not any(map(lambda r: l >= r, R)), L)

print(list(removeSubsumed(...)))
```